# General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I have three table (Company,Branch,medicines). i want that the primary key of " Company table" and " Branch table" are foreign key in " medicines-table "

```
class CreateMedicinesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->Integer('company-id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company-id')->references('company')->on('id');
            $table->Integer('branch-id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('branch-id')->references('branch')->on('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('potency');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

But the error is occured.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL  
  : alter table `medicines` add constraint `medicines_company_id_foreign` for  
  eign key (`company-id`) references `id` (`company`))                         



      [PDOException]                                                          
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint.
```

Comment: Do you have table engine set to `InnoDB` by default ?

Comment: No i don't. how to set table engine to InnoDB?

Comment: Add table engine to `InnoDB` as `MyIsam`  don't support relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:-

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company-id')->unsigned(); //Change here like this
        $table->foreign('company-id')->references('id')->on('company'); //Change here like this
        $table->integer('branch-id')->unsigned();  //Change here like this
        $table->foreign('branch-id')->references('id')->on('branch'); //Change here like this
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('potency');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Make sure `company` and `branch` table exist.

> Foreign Key like `tablename_id` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Always use underscore (_) for the name of your foreign keys . You will thank me later.

The error occurs because you try to create the foreign key of a table before creating the foreign table. 
Basicaly 1 solution is if you use artisan migration , just change the date on the migrations files so the company and branch table  have the oldest date in order to be created first. Or do it manually , there nothing else wrong